# Pre-calculeted field of view for efficiency

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm

I want a high performance field of view, on a grid like a rougelike. I know I could use the field of view algorithms out there, but I since this is for a server, I think could use some more resources, since using a pre-calculated field of view would be very wasteful to use on a client/single player.

What I'm thinking of is putting all the possibilities (I'm going with 21x21 map, so there are 441 spots: 441! / (2! (441 - 2)!) = 97020) into a file, the server reads the file, and puts the data into a unordered map of a vector of pairs of ints (the coord would be based off the position of the client, e.i.; `*pair*.first+client.x-11`). Then when a client sends a movement, the server gets the tiles around it, hashes it using boost, and sends the visible tiles (with delta compression of course!).

I would probably mess with bits and use 9 bit bytes instead of 8 because the max size is 441, and 8 bits max is 256, and 9 bits is 510.

What I am wondering is if the hashing will take more time than using a simple algorithm (not much experience with hashing...) or if this will take too much ram, but if not then I can flat out use the most complex and accurate algorithm without the processing time!

Comment: 256 * 2 = 510 ?!  %)

Comment: The max size of the grid is 441.